# Regex to match binary literal number in re2c format

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex, in RE2C's regex format ([1](https://re2c.org/manual/manual_c.html#regular-expressions)), for matching binary literal numbers. They should look like:

- 0b1, 0b101, 0b1111, 0b11_11, 0b1_111, 0b1_1_1_1, etc

The underscore is used as a convenience separator, and it is otherwise ignored when extracting the resulting digits. However, the separator should only be used in between digits (not at beginning nor end), and there should not be 2 or more consecutive underscores.

This is the regex that makes sense to me:

`BINARY_NUM = "0b" ("0"|"1") ("_"? ("0"|"1"))*;`

I'm trying to say:

- it starts with "0b"
- it is followed by one digit of 0 or 1.
- it is followed by any amount of any of these combinations: "0", "1", "_0", "_1"

However, the regex above also matches a trailing "_". So, these 2 are matched equivalently:

- 0b1_0
- 0b1_0_

How can I prevent the matching of trailing "_"?

Comment: I suspect it also matches "0b1_0X", then.  Is there some way to designate "end of token"?

Comment: It doesn't match 0b1_0X, actually. I don't see an end of token; only see end of (total) input.

Comment: I suspected you were going to say that, but given so, it's hard to see this as anything other than a bug in the product.

Comment: I'm using a workaround for it: inspect the end of the matched string in the handler code. Wanted to see if there was a "correct" way of fixing the regex; the workaround is good enough.

Comment: using the documentation, I wrote a [simple test](https://gist.github.com/jhnc/b51c8f570a13a0f15e5bc71a1358cf0a) using tags. the trailing characters don't seem to be treated as part of the token, so not clear what you're doing differently that means you are getting extra

Comment: That's a very good point.  Are you sure that "0b1_0_" is actually being matched?  Or is it matching "0b1_0", and "_" is left in the stream to be processed after?

Comment: I guess it's possible that my setup is somehow keeping an extra trailing character when the input has a trailing '_'. Though, I didn't find an error with my setup after inspecting it for issues; and this doesn't happen with other characters.

Comment: if you change `"_"` to `[_=]` (or one of the "doesn't happen with" characters) does it start to keep `=` also?

Answer (score 1):

Based purely on [this documentation](http://re2c.org/manual/manual_c.html#regular-expressions), a form of lookahead is supported.
So one might hope that this would work:

```
BINARY_NUM = "0b" ("0"|"1") ("_"? ("0"|"1"))* / [^_01] ;
```

or slightly more compactly:

```
BINARY_NUM = "0b" [01]+ ( "_" [01]+ )* / [^_01] ;
```

although something more sophisticated would be needed, since the example above implies that:

```
0b010101010222
```

would be parsed as `0b010101010` followed by `222`.

However, I discovered "trailing contexts are not allowed in named definitions" when I tried substituting the above into the [introductory sample code in the manual](http://re2c.org/manual/manual_c.html#introduction).

Modifying it with [the "sentinel" example](http://re2c.org/manual/manual_c.html#sentinel), I get:

```
// re2c $INPUT -o $OUTPUT -i --case-ranges
#include <assert.h>

bool lex(const char *s) {
    const char *YYCURSOR = s;
    const char *YYMARKER;
    for(;;) {
    /*!re2c
        re2c:yyfill:enable = 0;
        re2c:define:YYCTYPE = char;

        number = "0b" [01]+ ( "_" [01]+ )*;

        number { continue; }
        [\x00] { return true; }
        *      { return false; }
    */
    }
}

int main() {
    assert(lex("0b01_001"));
    assert(lex("0b00000_"));
    return 0;
}
```

This successfully rejects trailing `_`.

It is also possible to just include the null sentinel directly:

```
number = "Ob" [01]+ ("_"[01]+)* "\x00";
```

```
// re2c $INPUT -o $OUTPUT -i --case-ranges
#include <assert.h>

bool lex(const char *s) {
    const char *YYCURSOR = s;
    const char *YYMARKER;
    /*!re2c
        re2c:yyfill:enable = 0;
        re2c:define:YYCTYPE = char;

        number = "0b" [01]+ ( "_" [01]+ )* "\x00";

        number { return true; }
        *      { return false; }
    */
    }
}

int main() {
    assert(lex("0b01_001"));
    assert(lex("0b00000_"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The null matching at the end doesn't work for my usecase because those numbers are present as part of a larger chunk of text. Thus, there is likely to be more input after the binary number. I didn't try the lookahead one; I had though about it on my own, and I'm sure it wouldn't work well. Besides, I don't like the implication of the matching algo constantly inspecting lookahead tokens.

Comment: In the end, I have access to the matched value, so I'll just go ahead and manually inspect the matched input (in the action code) and issue an error when the trailing char is bogus. It's a roundabout way to accomplish what I asked, but it works for my case.

Comment: @Dess I'm surprised any of this is necessary: I would not expect the extraneous trailing `_` to be considered part of your BINARY_NUM and that there would be a failure when reading the token following (unless `_` is a valid prefix

Answer (score 0):

In regular regex style:

```
^0b([01]_?)*[01]$
```

The regex:

- `0b` literal "0b"
- `[01]_?` binary digit optionally followed by an underscore
- `(...)*` zero or more of
- `[01]` binary digit

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/eAAL7AcQp9WrH0).

Expressed as RE2C (I think):

```
BINARY_NUM = "0b" ([01]"_"?)* [01];
```

Comment: `$` is not valid as you can see in the documentation linked in the question, and `_` has to be `"_"`

Comment: as well as `0b` needing to be `"0b"` and `^` not being allowed

Comment: Right.  This is not a normal regular expression.  It's a special type.

Comment: @Tim is the RC2C version correct?

Comment: your re2c version is valid but it's simply an alternative way to write the re in the original question, as is mine (version without trailing context). neither address the problem that strings with trailing `_` are apparently still accepted. you can substiute your version into the [sample introductory code](http://re2c.org/manual/manual_c.html#introduction) with some testcases to demonstrate

Comment: however you can use my [version with tags](https://gist.github.com/jhnc/b51c8f570a13a0f15e5bc71a1358cf0a) to demonstrate that the re doesn't actually **match** the trailing `_` - I suspect this is something about the rest of OP program

Comment: @jhnc my regex does not match input with trailing underscore

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I said in the previous comment. the problem has nothing to do with the regex, so stating a correct regex doesn't answer the question. according to the OP, the string they get back after a match contains a trailing `_`. see comments on Q